# Error for display Backslash in Command Line?

Tags: windows, cmd, backslash, codepage-437

I think it's a rarely situation, when i try to type backslash() in my CMD it appear a ¥ instead as the picture below. It don't cause any error except in MYSQL cmd when i try to declare string with both single and double quotes like this:

'Knock-knock! Who\'s there? Boo! "Boo" who? Don\'t cry; it\'s only a joke!'

Can any one help me solve this problem ?,
Thank for your help.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwV67.png)

Comment: The YEN symbol is at the codepoint for REVERSE SOLIDUS (backslash) in Windows codepage 932. What is the output from the `CHCP` command?

Comment: Thank you so much, I solve this problem by change my code page.